# API Authentication with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I am basically trying to implement a User authentication system that POSTs information to an API/Web Service to cross-reference credentials, therefore rejecting them or allowing them to login.

I am not sure if I understand how this whole system works exactly, but I have been researching a lot on Authentication using Devise and APIs, and do not understand how none of the examples refer to the actual URI of the API at all.

For example, when I first began this process, I made sure to be able to connect to the web service through cURL:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"RuntimeEnvironment":1,"Email":"someone@example.com","Password":"Pa$$worD"}' -X POST http://blahblah/WebService/AuthenticateLogin
```

However in every single [blog post](https://hackhands.com/sign-users-ajax-using-devise-rails/) / [tutorial](http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-set-up-devise-ajax-authentication-with-rails-4-0/) / [guide](http://natashatherobot.com/devise-sign-up-ajax-rails/) / [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322062/api-authentication-using-devise-ruby-on-rails) I have been on, literally none of them specifically refer to the `http://blahblah/WebService/AuthenticateLogin` as I did in my cURL request.

- Am I searching for the wrong thing?
- Or is it actually there and I'm just not understanding?
- Also how do tokens factor into this scenario?
- The web service I am using does not require/return a token.

Comment: Can you paste your code in routes related to the endpoint /WebService/AuthenticateLogin ?

Comment: Well if I understood your question correctly, this Web Service is completely external and has nothing to do with my rails application, therefore I have nothing in my routes file to reflect that.

Comment: Then you are just searching for something wrong. All the resources are talking about building a JSON authentication system with Devise in Rails instead of using an external auth system.

Comment: Thank you @Yang. Is there standard way I should go about this? Or does Devise/other User Authentication tools not generally cover this?

Comment: If all your authentication is on an external API, you will just have to fetch the identifier of user (probably id or token) from the response. Create or update the user object in database and store the id or token in session to identify current user. That is everything I can come up with if you don't have any special requirements

Comment: Thank you. I think I am just going to follow http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch and try to use the rest-client gem in order to use the external API.